# SplitViewNavigator Flashing between Transitions

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex-mobile

This is a little difficult to describe so please bear with me.

Right now, I've got a `SplitViewNavigator` setup with a small `ViewNavigator` on the left for a menu and larger one on the right for content (I imagine that this is pretty obvious though). When I click on one of my options on the left, the content on the right transitions, as it should, to the appropriate view. However, the transitions also seem to involve a black box that flashes quickly on the bottom part of the right side `ViewNavigator` just before the new View is pushed onto the right side `ViewNavigator`.

Here is a picture of what I mean:

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/384321/black_flash_box.png]

I'm a little confounded as to why this is happening since I've never seen this before. For example, in the "phone friendly" version (which just pushes views around instead of using a `ViewNavigator`), this never occurs.

Although this doesn't affect functionality, it's really ugly and makes it look like the app is "flashing" anytime someone changes views which is even more frustrating in light of a normal phone interface.

Here's the code that I'm using to do the pushing in case that is relevant (I don't think it is because I learned about that method from Adobe):

```
var splitNavigator:SplitViewNavigator = navigator.parentNavigator as SplitViewNavigator;
var contentNavigator:ViewNavigator = splitNavigator.getViewNavigatorAt(1) as ViewNavigator;             
contentNavigator.pushView(Research);
```

Thoughts? I'm a bit of a novice so I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the trasnition or/and its direction?

```
        private var _slide:SlideViewTransition = new SlideViewTransition();

        private function init():void {
            _slide.direction = ViewTransitionDirection.DOWN;
            _slide.mode = SlideViewTransitionMode.PUSH;
        }

        contentNavigator.pushView(Research, null, null, _slide);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the transition doesn't help. The mysterious black box still flashes before the transition appears.